# How to mandate workflows to include local types assembly name?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am using WF4 and am having my types, activities and workflows in the same project and then I am using ActivityXamlServices.Load(path) to load my workflow activity and it throws the following exception:

```
The type ‘InArgument(local:,,,, of property ‘InputArgs’ could not be resolved
```

By looking at the solution to this problem at this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv/wfprerelease/thread/a29c22d6-cc41-48b2-b15b-f8c7912a04d1), I included assembly name manually in the workflow, and it all works.

Problem: Everytime I make any change in the workflow, it re-writes the xaml and removes the assembly names I manually added.

Question: Is there a way to mandate including assembly names of local types also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use a XamlXmlReaderSettings and specify what should be used as the local assembly reference.

```
var settings = new XamlXmlReaderSettings()
{
    LocalAssembly = typeof(YourArgumentType).Assembly
};
var reader = new XamlXmlReader(path, settings);
Activity workflow = ActivityXamlServices.Load(reader);
```

Comment: I just tried this good suggestion you made to my own similar question. It does solve the exception. However I seem to have lost layout information, the Points I think that loaded normally before. Some workflows load completely blank. Is there something else we have to do?

Comment: Not quite sure what is causing that. Maybe a .NET 4.0 to 4.5 conversion problem as the format of the workflows serialization has changed somewhat between the two. Loading a 4.0 workflow in 4.5 should just work but the other way around I am not so sure.

Comment: I will experiment as I don't need to support 4.0 at all but the workflows I was loading probably were 4.0. There is still that pesky vb in designer but 4.5 is c# expressions! Thanks